# How can I extract "Good Morning" from the provided image?

Tags: r, image-processing

I am trying to extract text from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4iDP.jpg). This is what I have tried:

```
install.packages("tesseract")
library(tesseract)
text4 <- ocr("goodmorning .jpg")
cat(text4)
```

and this is the output i get:

> What do you gain by Prayer ?
>       Best answer given
>       by Swami Vivekanand:
>       “I gained nothing,
>       In fact I Lost Anger,
>       Depression, J ealousy,
>       Irritation & Insecurity.”

The output **did not** extract "Good Morning". I need to extract Good Morning as well. Can you please point to me how can I extract good morning text as well?

**P.S.** I am not sure but I think "Good Morning" has been edited through phone on the screenshot of the image. This is probably a reason why **ocr** is not detecting the string.

Comment: Yup this is a duplicate. Thanks @Piglet for pointing it out.